# Express js middleware is not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, backend

is there something wrong with the middleware function or the way I am usinig it

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const test = require('./middleware/test')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(test)

app.get('/home', (req,res) => {
console.log('home')
res.send("home")
})
```

THE MIDDLEWAER FUNCTION IS IN THE MIDDLEWARE FOLDER

```
const test = ( err, req, res, next) => {
console.log("error mddleware is working")
next()
}
```

Comment: An error middleware is only called if an earlier middleware has raised an error: `next(err)`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I think this is just a normal middleware named like such, so it should be called. OP can you reproduce it somewhere? Or show more code

Comment: In addition to Heiko's comment, if that's the only code in your `errorHandler.js` file, you forgot the `module.exports =` part that you need for Node to know what `require` is supposed to return.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is working exactly as it should, op just expected it to do something that it doesn't do (with the express docs covering what it does more than adequately =)

Comment: please recheck the editted code, the problem is that I misunderstood middleware workflow, I thought that each middleware function should have the err argument @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: your post starts with "I followed all the docs", which is pretty clearly no true so really this is just one of those instance where you forgot to actually read the docs and follow the tutorials. That happens, but it's also a good reason to delete your post again, as you forgot to do the very first step mentioned in the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): researching express' error handling.

Answer (score 1):

middleware function was not running beacuse of the "err" argument.
If there is an err argument, then the middleware will not run until an error is thrown and passed through next()

Comment: That's not "the problem", that is [literally what the global error handler is supposed to do](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#the-default-error-handler). That's the whole reason  you _have_ a custom `errorHandler`: so it gets called when errors occur during route handling. If you didn't need that, why did you write one? =) Also, this should have been a comment on your own post, after which it'd probably even make sense to delete the post, given that you apparently wrote code you didn't want.

Comment: I misused the word "problem", I meant that beacuse of the err argument the middleware is not running

Comment: Sure, that was the very first comment you got on your post.

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSS, That was the problemmm, I searched everywhere no answer, thanks, I was taking the error but not using it, even though I replaced it with underscore, `(_, req, res, next)`, wasn't working till I totally removed it from params, `(req, res, next)`

Answer (score 0):

Add `module.exports = errorHandler` under your middleware function.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the error is used correctly. Always put the handler last, before the port listener :

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const errorHandler = require("./middleware/errorHandler")

app.use(express.json())

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  console.log("home")
  throw new Error("error")
  res.send("home")
})

app.use(errorHandler)
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server running on port 3000"))
```

Comment: No it doesn't, express explicitly uses the `next`-based callback methodology

Comment: Please double-check the update I stated above.

Comment: That, too, is incorrect. Express is quite cleverly written, and actually looks at the argument count to determine whether it's normal middelware (which uses 2 or 3 arguments) or the global error handler (which uses 4). You can bind the global error handler as early as you like.

Comment: Apology from my side, I didn't knew that the placement of the Error middleware do not matter. Thank you - @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans